# Need help to get Slider popup window

Tags: android

Friend's
   I need to get slider pop up window,when i click a tab control available at bottom.when i click the tab,i need to show the slider pop up from bottom to top animated to show the login button,after login i have to move my actual tab Activity.How can i get the view for slider pop up.

lets refer the screenshots,i attached here what i need exactly..

.[image]
From these when user to choose login at the time second screen appears looks like it.

[image]

How can i get the view like this above.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Get the sliding drawer view by id, cast it to a SlidingDrawer and then there is a function the SlidingDrawer object to pop it up.  You might have some weird issues though with screen state if users do stuff like hit back or close the slider.

To do what you need in the screenshot, do a sliding drawer with an empty handle and slide that up from the bottom as needed.  The sliding drawer is just another layout that can contain buttons, etc.

Here is an example:  http://www.androidpeople.com/android-sliding-drawer-example-tutorial/

Comment: revved answer above based on your new pictures